# How to remove HTML element from DOM with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a loader set up in a div that I want to remove once a certain component is loaded by react. This div exists in my index.html file out side of my components. The code for my div is:

```
<div class="loaderBackground">
   <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried using refs, but everything I have found seems to imply that the element would need to be in a component, which I would like to avoid.

Is it possible to remove the element without putting it in a component or do I have to fit in my components somewhere?

Comment: Can you just use CSS to display:none?

Comment: To do it from react find element using document.get....().style.display = none;

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly discourage using document.querySelector().. rather I would you React refs or state as said in the second answer but I would use conditional rendering as it doesn't impact styles which might have different states depending on other stuff

```
  this.setState({ hide: true });


  <div class="loaderBackground">
       {!hide && <div class="loader"></div>}
  </div>
```

Comment: I get the impression they're talking about a loader that's outside of the react app scope. With that said, I agree, they should probably put it inside of the react scope and do it this way. But it seems they explicitly don't want to do that.

Comment: Reading the question again I agree, still as you said I think it would be better to move it inside react scope and avoid using slow DOM API as it negates React performance features

Answer (score 2):

I propse to add a `state` that change to `true` after the loading to control the display of your DOM.

**Example:**

```
this.setState({ hide: true });

<div class="loaderBackground">
       <div class="loader" style={{display: hide? "none":"block"}}></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) should be a good place to put your logic.

```
var element = document.querySelector('.loader');
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

// or

element.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: there is no `OnComponentDidMount` as life cycle methods in react.

Comment: @G.aziz it's [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). I tried to edit this answer with that fixed but it isn't accepted yet.

Comment: i approved sorry i didn't see it

Comment: Thanks guys. Didn't see that.